# Inheritance in jsf

Tags: jsf, inheritance, el

I want to use inheritance in bean printed by jsf.
For example i have a parent class (animal) with two child's(cat and dog) with different attributes(catAttr and dogAttr) and a discriminator (type). I wanna print a list of animals with all its attributes.
Code example (it returns me a property not found exception), jsf page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:repeat value="#{animalsBean.animals}" var="a">
        <!-- General attributes -->
        <label>Name: </label> #{a.name}<br/>

        <!-- Specific attributes -->
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{a.type eq 'cat'}">
            <label>Cat attributes:</label>
            <h:inputTextarea value="#{a.catAttr}"/><br/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{a.type eq 'dog'}">
            <label>Dog attributes:</label>
            <h:inputTextarea value="#{a.dogAttr}"/><br/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:body>
```

AnimalsBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AnimalsBean {
    private List<Animal> animals;

    public List<Animal> getAnimals() {
        return animals;
    }

    public void setAnimals(List<Animal> animals) {
        this.animals = animals;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?
Thank's!

Answer (score 3):

The JSF tag components can't recognize the inner type of your model class (cat, dog, etc). If you're using the parent class, then you can only use the public attributes on it (that are general for all the children classes).

```
public class Animal {
    protected String name;
    //getter and setter...
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    private String specie;
    //getter and setter...
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public String race;
    //getter and setter...
}

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="animalBean")
public class AnimalsBean {
    private Cat cat;
    private Dog dog;
    private Animal animal;

    public AnimalsBean() {
        cat = new Cat();
        dog = new Dog();
        animal = new Cat();
    }

    //getters and setters...
}
```

The xhtml code for this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{animalBean.cat.specie}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{animalBean.dog.race}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{animalBean.animal.name}" />
    <!-- this line won't work -->
    <h:inputText value="#{animalBean.animal.specie}" />
</h:form>
```